# Using squid proxy as a way to change outgoing NIC

Tags: networking, router, proxy, network-adapter, squid

I've tried before to find a solution and I got really confused and not receiving an answer that fixed my problem (well the problem is actually my lack of knowledge here).

[What I am trying to achieve in a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWAkt.png)

I have a Linux (debian) Computer with 2 NIC on my local network.

- NIC 1 (Wifi) is connected to my main router GW (192.168.31.1) and have the static IP 192.168.31.33
- NIC 2 (USB) is connected to my 4G Phone GW (170.20.10.1) and have the static IP 170.20.10.2

I configured Squid to listen on port 3128 with the following configuration:

```
acl ip1 myip 192.168.31.33
tcp_outgoing_address 170.20.10.2 ip1

acl home src 192.168.31.33 #LocalIP
http_access allow home
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
server_persistant_connections off
```

Now I know it's not enough from here to establish a connection for 192.168.31.33:3128 to end up using gateway 170.20.10.1. But I'm not sure if it's a question of IP Masquerade (which I struggle to fully understand) or iproute.

Any help, link to ressources is appreciated!

EDIT:

ip a gives:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:f7:d7:03:7d:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:06:69:ce:33:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.31.33/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 38670sec preferred_lft 38670sec
    inet6 fe80::b338:170e:8e51:b04a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s20u1c4i2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:a3:95:a2:12:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 170.20.10.2/24 brd 170.20.10.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s20u1c4i2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::34a3:95ff:fea2:12a9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip r

```
default via 192.168.31.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
default via 170.20.10.1 dev enp0s20u1c4i2 proto static metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20u1c4i2 scope link metric 1000 
170.20.10.0/24 dev enp0s20u1c4i2 proto kernel scope link src 170.20.10.2 metric 100 
192.168.31.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.31.33 metric 600
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve source-based routing with a routing policy rule (`ip rule`) that looks up route(s) from a specific route table for a specific source. For example:

```
ip route add default via 172.20.10.1 table 123
ip rule add from 172.20.10.2 table 123
```

IP Masquerading is a type of source NAT, which means it only changes the source IP of a traffic (after it being "routed"). It does not determine which interface/gateway that the traffic goes through/to.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I Have this message appearing: "Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway" when i tried the first line.

Comment: Please so your `ip a` and `ip r` outputs. Looks like there's not even host route to the gateway or subnet route in the main table for the 4G IP.

Comment: If it's a point-to-point link, you can should probably replace `via $4g_gw` with `dev $4g_nic`. (Still you might need the `/32` IP to be added with the gateway as `peer`, if it isn't the case yet.)

Comment: Edited my main message

Comment: Well you have 170.x.x.x in the outputs but 172.x.x.x in your question (even your squid.conf).

Comment: You're right. big mistake here. I could implement the ip route & rule but yet after restarting my squid, my browser cannot access the web. (Thank a lot for your time)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100840/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-tayax).